# What is the minimum required to Run a .Net 3.5 Site WITHOUT compiling

Tags: iis, web-config, asp.net-3.5, compilation

Please note. Before anyone tells me about how I should compile the code for performance etc... this is just for a personal project and I want to be able to edit the code in a regular text editor and then it just works.

I usually code in C#, but this would be VB:

I have three files in a Virtual Directory

```
test.aspx
test.aspx.vb
web.config
```

I have copied the .Net 3.5 web.config line for line from a File > New Project.

It's not recognizing the XDocument class. Says, it's not `defined` Since this is a .Net 3.5 class, I figure it has to do with .Net 3.5

So, here's the question: Is this even possible to run a single page without compiling? Asp.Net should compile on the fly. It works with 2.0. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the assemblies to the web.config file (sorry cant recall the exact place to put it, but a normal VS generated one should have a few entries already).

Comment: Yeah, I have the whole web.config file from an empty project, including this entry `<add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
`

Comment: @Atømix: Did you include the namespace with `using` ?

Comment: Yep. Imports System.Xml.Linq and Imports System.Linq (Imports is the VB Equivalent)

Comment: In the end, I got it working, though I can't say exactly what it was that made it work. It was something in the VB that wasn't working. As a C# developer, it has me befuddled... but it works and since others will run into this... they will need to know to add the 3.5 assemblies into the web.config... so I accept your answer. :-)